# Pete's and Tom's computers

Tags: possessives, ambiguity

a. Pete's and Tom's computers were stolen.

Could the sentence be used if each had one computer?

Could the sentence be used if one had one computer and the other had more?

Could the sentence be used if each had their own computer or computers and they also owned one or more computers jointly?

Actually, I think the answer to all three questions is 'yes'. The last case is a bit strange, but not beyond the realm of possibility.

I don't think my third question has even been considered in the duplicate threads. This is 'hybrid' situation. The second question has not been addressed explicitly either, as far as I can see. The first question has arguably been answered indirectly.

It was clear to me from the beginning that with two apostrophe s's, the join ownership interpretation was out. And that is the issue addressed in the other threads, as far as I can see. But what if their is separate ownership and joint ownership? What if one has one computer while the other has ten? I don't think these issues have been dealt with in other threads.

Comment: The answer to all three questions is 'yes'.

Comment: Native speakers also get confused about this matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the use of possessive s with both words before the adjective](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/285369/the-use-of-possessive-s-with-both-words-before-the-adjective) Maybe not exact but there are other previous questions.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Possessive with Two Nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194073/possessive-with-two-nouns)

Comment: I've downvoted your post because it's possibly a duplicate, you can see the two comments from Weather Vane, or maybe they don't answer your question and you can edit it to explain where you still didn't understand??? Then I can retract my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes to all your questions, and yes, that sentence does hold ambiguity over the exact number of computers or the distribution of computers between the two people. It could be any of the cases you specified, although it is more likely that if there were multiple computers per person, or if 1 computer was jointly owned, it would have been explicitly mentioned to clear up such ambiguity.